# How to send Image as email attachment using Restful service

Tags: vb.net, email, rest

Below is the vb.net code that i'm using to receive an image  from jquery ajax call..

```
Public Function MailKpiChart(ByVal img As String) As GenericResponse(Of Boolean) Implements IKPI.MailKpiChart

        Dim SmtpServer As New Net.Mail.SmtpClient()
        SmtpServer.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential("xyz@gmail.com", "password")
        SmtpServer.Port = 587
        SmtpServer.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"
        SmtpServer.EnableSsl = True
        Dim blStatus As Boolean
        Try
            Dim mailMessage As New MailMessage()
            mailMessage.From = New MailAddress("from@gmail.com", ".Net Devoloper")
            mailMessage.To.Add(New MailAddress("to@gmail.com"))
            mailMessage.Subject = "test mail"
            mailMessage.Body = "hello world"
            Dim imgStream As New MemoryStream()
            Dim Image As System.Drawing.Bitmap = getImagefromBase64(img)
            Dim filename As String = "sample image"

            Image.Save(imgStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)
            mailMessage.Attachments.Add(New Attachment(imgStream, filename, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg))
            SmtpServer.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network
            SmtpServer.Send(mailMessage)
            blStatus = True
            Return ServiceUtility.BuildResponse(Of Boolean)(blStatus, String.Empty, String.Empty, 0)
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return ServiceUtility.BuildResponse(Of Boolean)(False, "",
        ex.Message, AppConstants.ErrorSeverityCodes.HIGH)
        End Try

    End Function
```

**and this is the function where i'm converting base64 string to an image**

```
 Public Function getImagefromBase64(ByVal uploadedImage As String) As Image
        'get a temp image from bytes, instead of loading from disk
        'data:image/gif;base64,
        'this image is a single pixel (black)
        Dim bytes As Byte() = Convert.FromBase64String(uploadedImage)

        Dim image__1 As Image
        Using ms As New MemoryStream(bytes)
            ms.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)
            image__1 = Image.FromStream(ms)
        End Using

        Return image__1
    End Function
```

and when i see my gmail inbox  i c a mail with an attachment but i dont see the actual image which i've sent..i just c a blank image

Help Needed

Regards

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and solved it by just adding the following line just before attaching the stream to the message.

imgStream.Position = 0

Regards,
Jonathan.

Comment: ohh ok..will check..thnx for the response..:)

Answer (score 0):

add your url - points to another web site

```
 Dim bodys As String = "<html><head><title> example </title></head><body><table width='100%'>"

    bodys += "<p><img width=135 height=77 src='http://www.example.com/image.gif'></p>"

    bodys += "</table></body></html>"

Dim mails As New System.Net.Mail.MailMessage()
        SmtpServer.Host = "127.0.0.1"
        SmtpServer.Port = 25

        mails = New System.Net.Mail.MailMessage()
        mails.From = New System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("example@example.com")
        mails.To.Add(txtEmail.Text)
        mails.Subject = ""
        mails.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8
        mails.IsBodyHtml = True

        mails.Body = bodys.ToString()


        SmtpServer.Send(mails)
```

A relative URL - points to a file within a web site

```
src="image.gif"
```

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_img_src.asp